# How to auto load apps in WAS LIberty 16.0.0.2? [it auto loads apps in 17.0.0.2 with the same configs]

Tags: websphere-liberty

So, we have two Liberty servers with different versions.

1. WAS Liberty 16.0.0.2, and
2. WAS Liberty 17.0.0.2

> Both of servers has the same configuration

But, the problem is, even with the same configuration, **WAS Liberty version 17.0.0.2** will auto load application context/servlet on start/restart without sending a request to them, while **WAS Liberty version 16.0.0.2** will not auto load application context/servlet on start/restart unless we send a request on it.

As per our search regarding this issue. In the [IBM Knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_servlet_load.html), it says that by default *Liberty defers servlet loading until a request is received for the associated web application*... but in **WAS Liberty version 17.0.0.2**, it will automatically load the servlet/application context.

Help will be very much appreciated for this one.

> **Note:** we did not add `<webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>` in our `server.xml`

Answer (score 2):

Liberty used to deploy the web application on first request. That was the behaviour in 16.0.0.2. I don’t recall exactly when we changed when we deploy, but we updated to deploy async during startup rather than on first request since a number of people were expecting their servlet inits to be triggered sooner than first request.

Comment: Hi @alasdair, thanks for you reply. So, in 16.0.0.2, it will not auto load application contexts?

Comment: @HazeErasmo it will if you configure deferServletLoad=“false”

Comment: I just want to clarify this @Alasdair, so in later versions, the default behavior was changed from "waiting a request to load  a context" to "load the context on startup".

Comment: And @Alastair, can we prevent apps in Liberty v17.0.0.2 to wait for a request before loading the application?

Comment: I wouldn’t quite describe it that way because we deploy the app async to startup so while it’ll start doing the initialisation during startup it isn’t guaranteed to complete deployment during startup. I’m not sure how to interpret your second question. Are you asking for the old behaviour?